# Retargeting on Unreal 5.x: unable to retrieve bone index for track

Tags: animation, unreal-engine5, unreal, retargeting, skeleton

I’ve made IK rigs for both my characters on my Unreal Engine 5.2.1, source and target. Then I’ve made a Retargeting IK, where I can see finally my target doing the source animation very well.

[image: my animation image]

So everything is perfect, but when I try to export my animation and then, open it, the character is static , no one bones is moved, and it move the full body like following the same path of the animation.

[image: animation retargeting result image]

When I look the logs I find various red lines reporting unable to retrieve bone index for track (name of the bone) for root pelvis, arm_l, etc. Where am I wrong? Is it not enough seeing the target on retargeting doing exaclty what I want?

[image: error logs image]